# Xamarin.Forms BoxView Height match Width

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the box view of a content page to 'FillAndExpand' horizontally while making the height equal to it's width. So far for the xaml I've got:

```
<ContentPage Title="About" >
<StackLayout>
    <BoxView x:Name ="imageBoxView" Color="AliceBlue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

But I don't know what value to keep for the Height Request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the binding context to itself, and then bind the `HeightRequest` to the view's `Width`.

**Note**: This will *not* work in the XAML preview mode in Visual Studio, but will work at runtime on the device.

```
    <StackLayout>
       <BoxView x:Name ="imageBoxView" Color="AliceBlue"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
          BindingContext="{x:Reference imageBoxView}" 
          HeightRequest="{Binding Width}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I'm new to bindings, how would I "bind the HeightRequest to the view's Width"? I know I can use imageBoxView.Width to get the width but what variable would I use for the binding?

Comment: @SamuelMungy I posted that in the XAML, look at the `BindingContext` and `HeightRequest` elements

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you